# Откуда ошибка "symbolic link privilege not held"?

Tags: python, распознавание-речи, speechbrain

Экспериментирую с моделью распознавания говорящего - библиотека speechbrain. Когда пытаюсь построить эмбединг для речи спикера, получаю ошибку:

> OSError: symbolic link privilege not held

Вот код

```
import torchaudio
from speechbrain.pretrained import EncoderClassifier
classifier = EncoderClassifier.from_hparams(source="speechbrain/spkrec-ecapa-voxceleb")
signal, fs =torchaudio.load('mine_1.m4a')
embeddings = classifier.encode_batch(signal)
```

Ошибка появляется в строке `classifier = EncoderClassifier.from_hparams(source="speechbrain/spkrec-ecapa-voxceleb")`

Что можно сделать, чтобы решить проблему? У меня Windows 10, версия Python 3.7.6

Comment: Запустить все то же самое, но с правами администратора.

Comment: @Eugene Krivenja, так оно с правами - я под учетной записью администратора в винде